# Golang io.Reader issue with jpeg.Decode returning EOF

Tags: image, go, jpeg

I am trying to take a multipart.File that is an io.Reader and decode it as a jpeg to covert into a Thumbnail using github.com/disintegration/imaging's library. I know in advance the data is going to be a jpeg. When I send the multipart.File to a ConvertImageToThumbnail function and it returns Unexpected EOF every time. What am I doing wrong?

```
package images

import (
    "github.com/disintegration/imaging"
    "image"
    "image/jpeg"
    "mime/multipart"
)

func ConvertImageToThumbnail(pic multipart.File) (image.Image, error) {
    pic.Seek(0,0) // The solution was to seek back to the beginning of the file
    img,err := jpeg.Decode(pic)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    thumb := imaging.Thumbnail(img, 100, 100, imaging.CatmullRom)

    return thumb, nil
}


pic, header, err := r.FormFile("avatar") 
// check error
defer pic.Close()
```

Comment: If there's a problem with the file you're passing to the decoder, you need to show us how you're generating that file.

Comment: why not save to a file and check? is the right image in jpeg format?

Comment: Are you sure that (`defer pic.Close()`) is not called before `ConvertImageToThumbnail`? Please post more code.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments, it's hard to read and belongs in the question. Also, That doesn't show *how* you're creating the file, nor does it show if it is actually a jpeg image. You need to debug what you're sending and receiving, not how you're decoding the image.

Comment: i would first check if img is a valid image by writing it out to a file or simply by fmt.Println(img.Pix) (do not forget to import "fmt") if the image is not to big.

Answer (score 4):

pic.Seek(0,0) before the decode fixed the issue.